# Wrap automatically into figure if not enough space to place it Here

Tags: floats, page-breaking

In many cases, I prefer to have a picture directly after the text, without caption... like that:
[image]

However, when there is no space for the picture (end of page...), I prefer to create a figure environment:

[image]

For now I need to manually change the code depending on which case I am, but it's really long and tedious to do (even once the document does not change too much), and it does not scale for big or changing documents (after any change I would need to recheck everything...) Any idea if I can automatize this process?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\section{If there is enough space}

\begin{definition}
  As you can see in this picture, A is a nice letter:
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{center}
\end{definition}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{If there is NOT enough space}

\begin{definition}\label{def:2}
  As you can see in \cref{fig:fig2}, A is a nice letter.
  \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Figure for \cref{def:2}}
  \label{fig:fig2}
\end{figure}
\end{definition}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Example of syntax}

I'd like to use a syntax like:
\begin{verbatim}
As you can see \figureIfSpace%
{in this picture, A is a nice letter:}% <- Text if space
{in \cref{fig:fig2}, A is a nice letter.}% <- Text if not enough space
{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}% <- Image...
[\caption{Figure for \cref{def:2}} \label{fig:fig2}]% <- Caption/labels
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I tried to solve this issue using `\pagetotal` to check the remaining space, but the obtained size seems to be too big: if I draw a rule of that size, it is pushed on the next page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]

\newdimen\spaceleft
\spaceleft=\dimexpr\textheight-\pagetotal-1mm\relax%
\rule{1mm}{\spaceleft}%
%Remaining space (above this line):
%\the\spaceleft
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, more of a suggestion. Take a look at the code of the `needspace` package, which checks if there is a certain amount of space left on a page. If there is not then it starts a new page. You might be able to do something similar regarding checking the available space but then do your own thing regarding (un)captioned illustration. I suppose you could always just include the graphic and use, or not, `\captionof` from the `caption` package.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Internally, it seems using something like I tried above, equivalent to: `\edef\measurepage{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax}`. But this is not precise enough apparently since `\rule{1mm}{\measurepage}` is always pushed on the newt page... So I need to remove some arbitrary amount of text to ensure it fits, and it's not great...