# Reliable way to know a (lower bound?) remaining space on the page

Tags: spacing, layout, penalty

In order to solve this question:

[Wrap automatically into figure if not enough space to place it Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617306/wrap-automatically-into-figure-if-not-enough-space-to-place-it-here/617341#617341)

I need to learn the remaining space on the current page.

I tried this to put a rule of exactly the good size, however this rule is pushed on the next page. Any idea why, and how I could know precisely the remaining available space?

If this is not possible, at least is there a way to have a (not too bad) lower bound, so that I'm guaranteed that the rule won't be pushed on next page? Or maybe I can add some penalty to help the rule to stay on this page?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\edef\measurepage{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax} %
\rule{1mm}{\measurepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

`\rule` is latex LR box so starts a new paragraph so starts `\baselineskip` (or as the rule is tall, `\lineskip`) below the point that you measured. You can suppress that with `\nointerlineskip`
You may also want to account for the depth below the final baseline so

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\showoutput
\showboxdepth4

\edef\measurepage{\the\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax}


\nopagebreak\nointerlineskip
\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{1mm}{\measurepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @tobiasBora --- If only I could predict the lottery numbers with [this level of accuracy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207782/2417).

Comment: @IanThompson :-)

Comment: note that this doesn't take account of stretch or shrink on the page, nor of floats that may be inserted by latex later on during the page make up. If a figure will be inserted at the top of thie page, it won't show up yet in `\pagetotal`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have 3 follow up questions: 1) why do I need to add the depth below the rule? (intuitively what is important is height+depth, so changing the depth without changing height+depth seems not important... but it is since otherwise rule is pushed on next line. 2) how can I measure the height+depth of a (potentially multilines) content, **including the baselineskip/lineskip** that could be added by the text? 3) where could I find myself all these informations about the internals of Tex/LaTeX? Is there a famous reference available online?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle really, floats are not counted? O_o looks annoying since it can heavily change the repartition on a given page... making this solution impossible to use in my problem. So how could I check if a content can fit on the current page to solve my initial problem ? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617306/wrap-automatically-into-figure-if-not-enough-space-to-place-it-here/617341#617341

Comment: @tobiasBora it's probably best you can do in a single pass otherwise you need to use `\pdfsavepos` and pick up exact measurements from the previous run